# Swift Decoder Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(VrOpsObjectStatistics!, from: Data)'

Tags: json, swift, struct, decodable, jsondecoder

**Hi Guys,**

I am decoding data which is coming from backend system to JSON with: 
`JSONDecoder().decode(<#T##type: Decodable.Protocol##Decodable.Protocol#>, from: <#T##Data#>)`.

I did it often for different kinds of data types, but this time I got the following error: `"Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(VrOpsObjectStatistics!, from: Data)"`

***Here is my struct and my partial code for the decoding procedure:***

My struct:

```
struct  VrOpsObjectStatistics : Decodable
{
    var resourceId: String
    struct StatList : Decodable
    {
        struct Stat : Decodable
        {
            var timestamps: [Date]
            struct StatKey : Decodable
            {
                var key: String
            }
            var statKey: StatKey
            var data: [Double]
        }
        var stat: [Stat]
    }

  }
    final class Ops
    {
            static let sharedVrOps  = VrOps();
            var vrOpsObjectStatistics : VrOpsObjectStatistics!;
        func decodeDataToJson(jsonData : Data, parsingType : String) -> 
(Bool, Any)
        {
         do  
         {
         self.vrOpsObjectStatistics = try 
      JSONDecoder().decode(vrOpsObjectStatistics.self, from: jsonData);
         }
    catch
            {
                print(error)
                return (false, error)
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(vrOpsObjectStatistics.self, from: jsonData);
```

to

```
JSONDecoder().decode(VrOpsObjectStatistics.self, from: jsonData)
```

The [`decode(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) method expects a meta-type of a type, which can be found by calling `.self` on a type and not an instance of that type. To find out more about the meta-type type have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html).